# Chrome WebDriver does not open when called from IIS

Tags: c#, selenium, iis, selenium-chromedriver

I have a really strange issue (And I have a really strong suspicion - that it will be on the IIS side).

I have `.NETCORE6` application, which uses Selenium via `IHostedService`.

There are cases that work:

- If I launch the application from Visual Studio's IIS locally the browser is opened
- If I launch the application from CMD (as self-hosted) the browser is opened
- If I launch the application from CMD (as self-hosted) on the server the browser is opened

BUT

If I launch the application from IIS on the server - the tests are running (looks like in headless mode) but the browser is not shown.

Does anybody have experience with IIS?

I have tried different IIS Pool Identity - and executed the app as a `DefaulPoolIdentity`, `LocalService`, `LocalSystem`, and even as my user which has admin rights - but the browser is still hidden.

Additional Notes:

- I also checked - that the browser is launching in maximized mode and on the correct screen

So the question is how to launch the app from the server via IIS with the web browser opened? (There just must be the solution for that right?)

Comment: Nothing in the system session (session 0) is visible to you, and not headless mode either. Time to learn the differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: I'm not sure but could you pls show us how you published your app to IIS? Per my experience, I usually publish my project to folder via VS, and then in the IIS to create a site to point to the folder I published my project.

Comment: I think Lex Li's answer is the correct one - and upon the article - it makes sense to me (thx btw).
The following question is - is the ANY chance for a workaround? (I know that I should not do it - just curious, if there is any way how to not use session 0...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex Li's answer is the correct one - so if anyone else finds the answer please read the article https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: is this answer or you still asking? what is the conclution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you start chromedriver manually and then call it using Selenium Grid the browser will open.

Driver configuration would be something like

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9515/"); --my chromedriver uri
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, new ChromeOptions());
...
```